# How to Capture Webcam in Python without using OpenCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, webcam

I want to capture a single shot of my webcam using python but without using OpenCV. The reason why is because whenever I compile the code to an executable, the source code goes up to 100mb and even more. OpenCV is a huge library and I'm just using a single feature so I don't really want to deal with extra space just because OpenCV is huge.

I tried using other libraries but they also depended on OpenCV and there weren't many to begin with. I hope you can give me an alternative or a solution to capture a webcam shot.

Comment: See [ask]. You need to be specific. Anyway, what about [PyAV](https://pyav.org/docs/stable/)?

Comment: @relent95 how much more specific do want this to be.

Comment: I mean you need to research more, choose a library, try to evaluate it and ask a question if you confront a problem. SO needs a specific question that can be answered with facts and citations. Your question in its current state is much likely to be answered with one's opinion. Just like what I said - 'what about PyAV'?

Comment: well thats what I needed cuz I've went over google for the past 3 days and it's just full of opencv. thats why I asked here so I know which libraries could achieve the same thing.

Comment: Yes I know. SO does not fit for that case. SO is not for a discussion. It's enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ImageIO library to accomplish your needs.

```
import imageio as iio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
camera = iio.get_reader("<video0>")
photo = camera.get_data(0)
camera.close()
plt.imshow(photo)
```

Source: [Webcam Capture In Python (without OpenCV)](https://sebastianwallkoetter.wordpress.com/2021/03/07/webcam-in-python/)